# How to return a NEW object with same keys but with different values

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I am having a hard time to figure this out.

I am using redux in my app and want to return a completely new object from my switch statement. Lets say we have an initial state and then when a componentWillMount we make an ajax request and we want to override the initial state with these new values. The keys of the object from the ajax request are the SAME as the initial state object. However, the values obviously changed. What is the most efficient and clean way to return a new javascript object?

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  name: "",
  email: "",
  phoneNumber: "",
  uid: "",
  photoURL: "",
  address: {
    city: "",
    country: "",
    street: "",
    details: ""
  },
  pastOffers: [],
  memberSince: "",
  gender: "",
  birthday: "",
  description: "",
  worker: false
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USER_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, HOW DO I INSERT ACTION.PAYLOAD HERE };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I was thinking of using lodash and doing a _.each() and then passing an object to the reducer with (prop, value) and  then doing:

```
return { ...state, [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value }
```

but that seems a little too much. Is there any simpler way?

Comment: Object.assign({...},initial_state);

Comment: @Jonasw Can you elaborate?

Comment: What is the action's payload?

Comment: @OriDrori the actions payload is the same as the initial object but with the values filled in.

Comment: @FazalRasel Thank you, no thank you.

Comment: or couldnt you do {...state,...actions.payload} ?

Comment: If it's the same structure, just return the payload.

Comment: @OriDrori I tried that but I got the infamous red screen.

Comment: @Jonasw I was not using the ... before action.payload maybe that solves it?

Comment: You've tried this -  `return action.payload;`, and you've got an error?

Comment: @OriDrori I know that could work but I still need to return the Initial state.
This is what I had return { ...state, action.payload }

Comment: @OriDrori It is kind of expecting a key? When I put ... in front of action.payload the error goes away.

Comment: Indeed. You've copied the new payload on the old state. It's the same as just returning the new payload.

Comment: I've missed that in your previous comment `{ ...state, action.payload } ` - this is an error. This - `{ ...state, ...action.payload }` spreads them both into a new object.

Comment: So I do need the ... !! Thank you @OriDrori

Comment: Welcome, but @Jonasw said it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either copy both objects into a new one:

```
{...state,...actions.payload}

Object.assign({},state,actions.payload);
```

or use inheritance maybe:

```
Object.create(state,actions.payload);
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this example with user service:

```
const initialState = {
    fetching: false,
    fetched: false,
    users: [],
    error: null,
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "FETCH_USERS_PENDING":
            {
                return { ...state,
                    fetching: true
                }
                break;
            }
        case "FETCH_USERS_REJECTED":
            {
                return { ...state,
                    fetching: false,
                    error: action.payload
                }
                break;
            }
        case "FETCH_USERS_FULFILLED":
            {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    fetching: false,
                    fetched: true,
                    users: action.payload,
                }
                break;
            }
    }
    return state
}
store.dispatch({
    type: "FETCH_USERS",
    payload: /* user service */
})
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript tries to be clever when manipulating objects.

If you have a CONST and you want to return a new instance every time. Then I assign the object as a string which you never manipulate. When you want a new instance of this "object" then you can create the object there and then.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = '{ "name": "", "email": "", "phoneNumber" : "", "uid" : "", "photoURL" : "", "address": { "city": "", "country": "", "street": "", "details" : "" }, "pastOffers" : [], "memberSince": "", "gender": "", "birthday": "", "description": "","worker": false };
```

Now you have a string object with your defined schema. Returning new instances is as simple as

```
function getNewInstance() {
  var newInstance = JSON.parse(INITIAL_STATE);
  newInstance["name"] = "Joe Bloggs";
  newInstance["email"] = "Joe@bloggs";
  return newInstance;
}
```

Alternatively you just declare the object there and then and return the new instance prepopulated.

```
function getNewInstance(name, email, phoneNumber) {
    return {
      "name": name,
      "email": email,
      "phoneNumber": phoneNumber,
      "uid": "",
      "photoURL": "",
      "address": {
        "city": "",
        "country": "",
        "street": "",
        "details": ""
      },
      "pastOffers": [],
      "memberSince": "",
      "gender": "",
      "birthday": "",
      "description": "",
      "worker": false
    };
}
```